# SimplePie parsing to Find Youtube Video link

Tags: php, xml, parsing, simplepie

I'm using SimplePie to parse our church RSS Feed which contains weekly sermons, both audio and video.  I'm able to get the title and mp3 link, but having a difficult time getting the youtube link.  Below is a sample of what is in the XML feed containing the youtube video.

It's using `[CDATA]`

I'm using `$item->get_content()`, but that doesn't seem to contain any of the tag data below.  The url for the feed is http://lakeforest.org/feed.  When I bring this url up in the browser I can see the embedded youtube video.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

NOTE: - i commented the html below for display only

```
<!--
<description><![CDATA[Huntersville Campus Mike Moses, Lead Pastor Series Discussion Questions: SHAPE, Part 2 Spiritual Gifts Inventory VIDEO AUDIO]]></description>
                <content:encoded><![CDATA[<h3>Huntersville Campus</h3>
<p>Mike Moses, Lead Pastor<br />
<a href="http://lakeforest.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/SDQ_SHAPEPt2.pdf">Series Discussion Questions: SHAPE, Part 2</a><br />
<a href="http://www.churchgrowth.org/cgi-cg/gifts.cgi?intro=1 <http://www.churchgrowth.org/cgi-cg/gifts.cgi?intro=1" target="_blank">Spiritual Gifts Inventory</a></p>
<h4>VIDEO</h4>
<p><iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/4Uv8U8c6isg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></p>
<h4>AUDIO</h4>
<img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/LakeForest/~4/qMoLVpI1tGI" height="1" width="1"/>]]>  -->
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($item->get_content());` give?

Answer (score 2):

SimplePie strips out `embed`, `object`, `iframe` etc tags by default as they can be dangerous.

You should ignore them if you want the video back, but be careful with the source url as it could be a security issue.

```
$feed = new SimplePie();
$feed->set_feed_url('http://simplepie.org/blog/feed/');

// Remove these tags from the list
$strip_htmltags = $feed->strip_htmltags;
array_splice($strip_htmltags, array_search('object', $strip_htmltags), 1);
array_splice($strip_htmltags, array_search('param', $strip_htmltags), 1);
array_splice($strip_htmltags, array_search('embed', $strip_htmltags), 1);
array_splice($strip_htmltags, array_search('iframe', $strip_htmltags), 1);

$feed->strip_htmltags($strip_htmltags);
```

[Source](http://simplepie.org/wiki/reference/simplepie/strip_htmltags#remove_object_param_and_embed_from_the_default_list)

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed your feed URL, that wasn't what I was expecting, I was expecting something like this:

> http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/videos?q=painting+miniatures+tutorial&orderby=published&client=ytapi-youtube-search&v=2

That is a search result feed from YouTube which I pass to SimplePie [here](http://news.muschamp.ca). Also the rest of your PHP code where you declare $item would be useful. I answered a similar question tonight and basically over the years YouTube has changed their API and feeds, you might have to update to a newer version of their API/feed even if you can find old examples of it working.

SimplePie can handle some if not all YouTube feeds, but there is no guarantee Google (YouTube) will give you a thumbnail and all the metadata they have on YouTube.com. APIs usually make a subset of the data contained in their database available via APIs, they want people to come to their website so they can show them ads and track them better.

Not the answer you want perhaps but without more information, that is the best I can do.

If you want to dig into the feed and get the video URL and then create a player for it, that is non-trivial. You have to use something like simple_html_dom then you need to create a properly formatted iframe or javascript call to create the in browser player. SimplePie doesn't have a get_contents()->video

Comment: If your feed was in one of the newer formats, perhaps MediaRSS this would be easier...